# Clojure : "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No value supplied for key:" when I changed require

Tags: clojure, require, destructuring

I'm getting a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No value supplied for key:` in my Clojure code.

I know this is what happens when I'm trying to destructure the keys in a mapping passed as an argument.

However, what's odd here is that this function has been working fine for ages, with the same data. And the only thing that seems to be different is how I'm now importing the function

Here's the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No value supplied for key: 
{:style {:color [255 150 150 255], :stroke-weight 2}, :points [[-1 0] [0 -1] [1 0] [0 1] [-1 0]]}
```

And here's the function that threw it.

```
(defn scale
  [val {:keys [style points]}]
  {:style style
   :points (scale-shape val points)})
```

In other words, I'm asking for the map to contain keys called `style` and `points` and it's being given a map which contains keys called `style` and `points`.

And this code has been working fine for months.

The difference is that I'm now calling it using `sshapes/scale` where `sshapes` was imported with:

```
 (:require [patterning.sshapes :as sshapes])
```

whereas previously I was just calling it as `scale` where scale came into the namespace using

```
 (:require [patterning.sshapes :refer :all])
```

Could this cause that kind of error?

Comment: Is it possible that :refer :all was pulling in another function that you were using before?  (For example, what about `scale-shapes`?) Now that this other function not being pulled in, maybe you're using a function of the same name from a different namespace, and it's not generating something in the format that `sshapes/scale` expects.

Comment: Good thought. It can't be exactly that, but it's possible in my rewriting I have mixed up a call to the lower-level scale-shapes and this scale function. Though it's weird because the error message seems to imply I'm sending a map with the right keys.

Comment: The code you have provided is not enough to figure out what's going on - the exception is coming from somewhere else in your program, probably in whatever function calls `scale`. Please include the relevant code or at least a full stacktrace, if you need help debugging an error message.

Comment: @amalloy It really is coming from that function.

Comment: Got a snippet we can run that reliably reproduces that error?

Comment: @BradKoch It's complicated. That error has appeared as I'm trying to migrate my code to cljx so that I can compile and run it in the browser. In order to do that, I've changed the way I'm "requiring". After which, all my transformation functions (scale, rotate, stretch etc.), which take the same argument structure, have broken. I'm in the process of rearranging things more drastically (and hoping the problem will disappear). If not I'll post a longer example of the reorganized code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK. I changed the code to use

```
(:require [patterning.sshapes :refer [scale rotate]])
```

ie. with the required functions named explicitly, did a lein clean, and the problem has disappeared. The function definitions themselves and the code which calls them remain the same.

Weird.