# What causes "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No value supplied for key"?

Tags: clojure, destructuring

I have code of the shape

```
(let [{foo :foo} (make-foo)] ...)
```

This code occasionally emits a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No value supplied for key: {:foo "foo" :other "other"}`.

I've seen [Clojure : "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No value supplied for key:" when I changed require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24582624/clojure-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-no-value-supplied-for-key-when), however I haven't changed the require of my program since it last worked.

**What are the possible causes for the "No value supplied for key" exception?**

Comment: I found the solution to my particular problem. Still I think it would be useful to have an answer to the general question of what scenarios can cause this exception. For those curious about my specific issue, `make-foo` was actually returning `[{:foo "foo"}]` instead of `{:foo "foo"}`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This happens when you try to create a map from an odd number of key/value entries: the last key is missing a value. One way this can happen is when destructuring a non-map collection but treating it as a map, since this implicitly creates a map from the collection for you before destructuring it as an ordinary map.