# YeSQL: Which key needs a value?

Tags: clojure

I was following basic YeSQL tutorial and copied code from [here](https://github.com/krisajenkins/yesql) and I have error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No value supplied for key: {:identifiers #object[clojure.string$lower_case 0x7c31e410 "clojure.string$lower_case@7c31e410"], :row-fn #object[clojure.core$identity 0x6febec41 "clojure.core$identity@6febec41"], :result-set-fn #object[clojure.core$doall 0x4e8afdad "clojure.core$doall@4e8afdad"]}
    at clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap.create(PersistentHashMap.java:77)
    at clojure.java.jdbc$query.invokeStatic(jdbc.clj:756)
    at clojure.java.jdbc$query.doInvoke(jdbc.clj:756)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:442)
    at yesql.generate$query_handler.invokeStatic(generate.clj:89)
    at yesql.generate$query_handler.invoke(generate.clj:82)
    at yesql.generate$generate_query_fn$real_fn__1710.invoke(generate.clj:120)
    at yesql.generate$generate_query_fn$query_wrapper_fn__1715.invoke(generate.clj:139)
    at yesql.generate$generate_query_fn$query_wrapper_fn__1715.invoke(generate.clj:138)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
    at clojure.lang.AFunction$1.doInvoke(AFunction.java:29)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at aplikacija.core$_main.invokeStatic(core.clj:15)
    at aplikacija.core$_main.doInvoke(core.clj:14)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:375)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:646)
    at clojure.main$main_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:314)
    at clojure.main$main_opt.invoke(main.clj:310)
    at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:421)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:384)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
```

I was looking for solution and came up with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47037220/what-causes-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-no-value-supplied-for-key) but I don't see which key need value. Is there some better way how I can debug or it is clear from this message where the problem is? I am trying simple select in db. Here is my code:

```
(ns aplikacija.core (require [yesql.core :refer [defqueries]]))



(def db-spec {:classname "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
              :subprotocol "oracle:thin"
              :subname "address:port/db"
              :user "xxx"
              :password "xxx"})

(defqueries "sql/query.sql"
            {:connection db-spec})

(defn -main [& args]
  (println (posAll {:id 10})))
```

And query is

```
-- name: posAll
SELECT *
FROM pos
WHERE POS_ID = :id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown by `clojure.java.jdbc` when it tries to internally construct a map with the actual JDBC options as a map. It should be able to use the options map as-is, so there is definitely something amiss.

A simple example why the Exception is thrown:

```
(PersistentHashMap/create '({:A 42}))
IllegalArgumentException No value supplied for key: {:A 42} ...
(PersistentHashMap/create '({:A 42} "foo"))
=> {{:A 42} "foo"}
```

I tried running your example as given, although replacing the DB with Postgresql, and it worked fine. However, I noticed that the `clojure.java.jdbc` and `yesql` versions are very prone for mismatches. For example, replacing `yesql` with `0.5.2` in the deps below caused build time failures.

Nonetheless, taking the latest versions did seem to work for me. These were at the time of writing:

```
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [yesql "0.5.3"]
                 [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.7.8"]
                 [org.postgresql/postgresql "42.2.4"]]
```

Note also that 1) `yesql` is not actively maintained at the moment ([Frozen. Maintainer sought.](https://github.com/krisajenkins/yesql)), and 2) Oracle is not listed as [supported DB for `org.clojure/java.jdbc`](https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc#releases-and-dependency-information).

Comment: I have tried with [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.3.3"]. When I update version to 0.7.8. it works